# Making a dictionary from a dataframe and a Pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset with **n features + 1 target** column that I am using to train a machine learning model.

To do this, from the original df I do:

```
X=df.drop('target', axis=1)
Y=df['target']
```

Then I have **dataframe X** with all features and a **pandas.Series Y** with that target column, named `Y`.

Now, I want to merge this two structure in a python dict (or json) to use it as a stream of data and iterate over it, like:

```
for X, Y in new_object
```

i read this [Making a dictionary from pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878091/making-a-dictionary-from-pandas-dataframes) but in the end I could not get this iterable dict.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you'd like each iteration to do? I'm guessing you want it to return a row of the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
for x, y in zip(X.values, Y.values):
```